# unable to correctly sort dates with milliseconds

Tags: elasticsearch

With a mapping definition of seconds:

```
  "time": {
           "type": "date",
           "store": "yes",
           "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss",
           "index": "analyzed"
        },
```

the time field is sorted "desc" and "asc" correctly

However we need milli-second accuracy

```
  "time": {
           "type": "date",
           "store": "yes",
           "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
           "index": "analyzed"
        },
```

then oddly the sort on  "asc" is returning the sort order 
while sort on "desc" is returning the correct milli-second order

Comment: As far as I can see using _mapping call "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" translates correctly as a date but "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" seems to get converted to a "String" causing the sort to be incorrect

Answer (score 3):

to answer my own question .. the custom mapping syntax was incorrect. A corrected version is
below that correctly sorts on dates  with milliseconds.

The only minor remaining question is how and why the incorrect format was accepted and how to prevent that.

```
POST test2
{
   "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
},
"mappings": {
  "logevent": {
     "properties": {
        "logtime": {
           "type": "date",
           "store": "yes",
           "format": "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        },
        "eventKey": {
           "type": "string",
           "store": "yes",
           "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "channelid": {
           "type": "string",
           "store": "yes",
           "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "eventtype": {
           "type": "string",
           "store": "yes",
           "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "step": {
           "type": "string",
           "store": "yes",
           "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "line": {
           "type": "string",
           "store": "yes",
           "index": "analyzed"
        }
     }
  }
   }
}
```